# How can I build a class around a pandas dataframe that contains extra columns that are ignored when accessing the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rework some code that contains a class with a Pandas DataFrame container for it's data.  I have implemented the class with a large number of columns that encompass all the possible data, but are often not all full, ie: some columns are all null valued.  I would like to introduce a mechanism that will limit the output of the accessor my_class_instance.data to the columns that have data only.  I tried the following, but the test.data['key'] = value lines have no effect with it is calling the getter property that returns nothing due to the implementation.

```
import pandas as pd

class MyData:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])


    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data.loc[:, self._data.notnull().all()]

    @data.setter
    def data(self, d):
        self._data = d

test = MyData()
test.data['A'] = np.ones(2)
test.data['B'] = np.nan

test.data
```

Can someone suggest a fix to this method, or an alternative to using the @property decorator that will achieve the desired outcome:

```
>>test.data

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop columns when they contain NaN values, use [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with the `axis=1` parameter.

Try with this;

```
class MyData:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])


    @property
    def data(self):
        # drop columns containing NaN values
        return self._data.dropna(axis=1, how='any')

    @data.setter
    def data(self, d):
        self._data = d
```